# Alternative to Coefficient List

Tags: special-functions, code

I was using CoeffientList to get the probabilities of this generating function...

```
 CoefficientList[((r[PoissonDistribution[1], j]*z + 1 - r[PoissonDistribution[1], j]))^3, z] /. {j -> 5}

 {0.00427933, 0.0662369, 0.341745, 0.587738}
```

But when I try to use it with this function

```
 CoefficientList[((1 - r[PoissonDistribution[1], j])/(1- z*r[PoissonDistribution[1], j])),z]/.{j->5}
```

It says it can't do it because it's not a polynomial.

Is there any other way in Mathematica to get the probabilities of the above generating function with a similar "coefficient function" for non-polynomials?

Thanks for assistance...

EDIT: The r function is here...

```
 r[dist_, j_] := N[PDF[dist, j]/(1 - CDF[dist, j - 1])
```

Comment: Have you seen `Series` for generating power series?

Comment: `SeriesCoefficient` too: `SeriesCoefficient [(1 - X)/(1 - z*X), {z, 0, 5}]` . What is `r` ? See also: [`GeneratingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeneratingFunction.html).

Comment: I forgot to put the "r" function - it's there now - Thanks